# Recyclerview range selection

Tags: android-recyclerview

I work currently on implementing recyclerview-selection library.
I flowed integration process from the official documentation, but i want to deactivate range selection.

Anyone already know how to do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deactivate certain items from being selected (long-press) by using a `SelectionPredicate<K>`.

An example on how to do that can be found here: https://github.com/ExpensiveBelly/RecyclerViewSelection

More specifically in the class `ItemsAdapter`, which only allows selection on those items that match a certain predicate.